# Problem with a Flappy Bird Clone in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assets\PipeMiddleScript.cs(25,18): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'scoreToAdd' of 'LogicScript.addScore(int)'

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int playerScore;
   public Text scoreText;

   [ContextMenu("Increase Score")]
   public void addScore(int scoreToAdd)
   {
       playerScore = playerScore + scoreToAdd;
       scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();
   }
   
   public void restartGame()
   {
      
      SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

   } 
   

}
```

Comment: The problem i think is in this line:"SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);"

Comment: And also the space in the first line is not in the original code.The space is just a mistake when i have copied the code.

Comment: We don't have your `PipeMiddleScript` (which is where the error actually comes from) but you seem to be trying to call `addScore()` without any parameters but it requires one `int scoreToAdd` ...